# Table in dataset in vb.net is not saving as a foxpro table

Tags: vb.net, oledbconnection

I have a dataset in vb.net. I have read a few tables from visual foxpro and added tables in the dataset. A new table is created in the dataset. I now want to create a new dbf file from vb.net which is this new Table.
But the SQL is not accepting the source table and gives an error.
The relevant part of the code is shown.

```
     Dim NewTable As String
     NewTable = "Test.DBF"
     connstr = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source="
     connStr2 = connstr & sourceDir & "\"
     Dim sourceTable As DataTable
     sourceTable = myDS.Tables(3).Copy

     NewTable = sourceDir & "\" & NewTable

     Dim oConn As OleDbConnection
     Dim oCmd As OleDbCommand

     oConn = New OleDbConnection(connStr2)
     oCmd = New OleDbCommand()
     oCmd.Connection = oConn
     oCmd.Connection.Open()
     oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & sourceTable.ToString & " INTO TABLE " &    NewTable
    oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    oConn.Close()
```

The error is while executing the oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
File out1.dbf does not exist. 
(out1.dbf is the name of myDS.Tables(3).name)
So how do I proceed? 
Thanks for the help, in advance.

Comment: Try dropping the `.dbf` extension and just use the file name (i..e, `out1` and `TEST`).

Comment: I have named sourceTable as "out1". There is no .dbf from my side into the dataset. I did drop from Test. It appears that the command is looking for a 'Real' table by the name out1. I do not know how to reference a table in dataset from SQL

Comment: `sourceTable` is an in-memory table - but the command is going to look for it in the directory specified by the connection string.  You would probably need to create the table and then select insert (two commands instead of one).  Not 100% sure how you would do that in FoxPro, or if it can even be done (though I'm pretty sure it could be).

Comment: Yeah that is the problem. I want to create a table that exists in the dataset memory to a 'physical dbf' file.